# flutter fl-chart spots with Hive

Tags: flutter, fl-chart

i'm having issues while implementing line Chart especially with spots. i want to track a progress every week (every 7 days)
and i have already the list of these numbers which i want to display it. please note that everyday this list is adding a new number (i'm using hive as my local storage) the idea is as follow:

```
final dailyCaloriesBox = Hive.box('dailyCalories');
final now = DateTime.now();
final key = '${now.year}-${now.month}-${now.day}'; // it means that everyday this String value will be change
final caloriesBurned = burned; //this number is changing everyday
dailyCaloriesBox.put(key, caloriesBurned); // everyday it will add the new burned calories value

final entries = dailyCaloriesBox .values; // this one displays all the values of the box,
final entries_map = dailyCaloriesBox .toMap(); this one displays all the the data of the box as a map

// i don't know what should i use inside spots..list or map ?
```

my problem is i dont know what to type exactly inside spots to display the value in its day
and another problem that i'm wondering how to solve it.. when the first 7 days are finished..the next day the list will be incremented by +1 index so as total it will be 8 days..so i want when i finish the first 7 days it will make another PageView that shows the progress of the line chart of the new next 7 days.

i know i'm asking for too much but im really a beginner at flutter